# How to resolve "test-life cycle-and-artifact Handler1.pom.sha1 " cannot creat on maven installiton

Tags: maven

I need your help.
I downloaded maven 3-5-0-src.zip file from maven site. I started to unzip process after a few seconds I got an this error.

> Error: System doesn't find this path.
>   Cannot create
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\wz85b2\apache-maven-3.5.0\maven-core\src\test\resources\org\apache\maven\extension\test-extension-repo\org\apache\maven\core\test\test-lifecycle-and-artifactHandler\1\test-lifecycle-and-artifactHandler-1.pom.sha1.

I can't install maven on my computer. How can solve this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://maven.apache.org/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ...-src.zip file only contains the source files for your reference.

You need to download and install the binary zip file at [apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip](http://apache.uberglobalmirror.com/maven/maven-3/3.5.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip) if you're planning to use maven to build stuff.

Otherwise, the above error looks suspiciously like a Windows path length problem.